# What is the difference between overloading the assignment operator and any other operator?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I want to know if there is any difference between simple binary operator overloading and assignment operator overloading.

Comment: Please fix your title and your shift key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three I should have swung the dupe hammer in 1st place.

Comment: [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two differences:

1. An overloaded assignment operator must be a member of the class being assigned to; it cannot be declared as a free function.
2. Copy and move assignment operators will be implicitly declared for your class if you do not declare them yourself (subject to certain restrictions).